# Octopus-deploy; transform files being deleted

Tags: transform, octopus-deploy

When we ran our deploy from octopus deploy, we failed on our last step. I will include the error message, but the main problem is that it seems to be deleting our transform files. We have the checkbox marked to automatically run configuration transform files, but it results in them being deleted. Anyone else run into this problem or possibly know how to fix it?

The error message is:
Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a non-null value.

When we went to check the files from there, we noticed they were being deleted.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are actually being copied to the build path during a build? Perhaps you could mark them "Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always" to test.

Answer (score 0):

Octopus deletes the config transforms after executing them by design. That is not causing your deployment to fail.

Your release is failing because you are calling the PowerShell cmdlet `Set-Location` and passing a null value to its `Path` parameter.

Comment: I'm guessing things have changed since this was written, because I don't think Octopus deletes config transforms after executing them. For example, there is a community step to do this: [File System - Clean Configuration Transforms](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/9a2b84db-2940-4d9a-b61f-c82df35cee6c/actiontemplate-file-system-clean-configuration-transforms). If we don't use that step, the files are left there.